# Filtrar con ComboBox y TextBox enc# SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, filtro

Tengo que filtrar los datos de un datagrid con un textview y un combo box. 
Pero, ocurre lo siguiente: el combo inicializa en 0 por lo que no me capta el valor del primer item. Intente agregar un item manualmente para que el valor 0 sea "Seleccione" y los demás sean de la base de datos.

Error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede modificar la colección Items cuando está establecida la propiedad DataSource.'
```

En el siguiente método intento formular la query de sql para que tome los parámetros (combobox y textbox) y realizar el filtro en el datagrid:

```
private void filtrarTituloYAEMP(int valor){
cmbTipoPago.Items.Add("Seleccione");
            if (txtTitulo.Text == null || txtTitulo.Text == ""){
                try{
                    llenaTitulo();
                }catch (SqlException ex){
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            else{
                try{
                    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
                    conexion.ConnectionString = "acá mi conexión a la bd";
                    conexion.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();


     string sSQL = "SELECT titulo FROM V_CuetaWeb, ArchivoElectronico_MedioPago where titulo LIKE @valor + '%' and AEMP_Id = @id";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion);
                command.Parameters.Add("@valor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valor;
                command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipoPago.SelectedValue);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                da.Fill(ds, "V_CuetaWeb");
                conexion.Close();
                dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds;
                dtgTitulo.DataMember = "V_CuetaWeb";
            }catch (SqlException exx){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exx.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Claramente, así no funciona. Entonces, los problemas son:

1- Que el ComboBox tenga una opción extra('Seleccione') que tome el valor 0

2- Que el método filtre con el textbox y el combobox

¿Alguien tiene idea de como lograr arreglar esos detalles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como bien lo dice la excepción no puedes agregarle items por medio de la propiedad `cmbTipoPago.Items.Add("Seleccione");` ya que anteriormente fue llenado con un `DataSource`, puedes usar la propiedad `SelectedItem`, asi evitas tener que agregar el item `seleccione`, ya que esta propiedad volvedera el item seleccionado.

```
        if (cmbTipoPago.SelectedItem is null)
        {
            ///seleccione un item valido
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipoPago.SelectedItem);
        }
```

En caso de que quieras agregar la opción `seleccione` podes traerlo desde la base de datos.

```
SELECT 'SELECCIONE'
UNION ALL
-- su sql
```

---

```
        if (cmbTipoPago.SelectedItem is null || cmbTipoPago.SelectedItem.ToString() == "SELECCIONE")
        {
            ///seleccione un item valido
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipoPago.SelectedItem);
        }
```